# Working with 'Workflow Gem in rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working using Workflow gem to integrate a workflow for my model.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
......
include Workflow
  workflow do
     state :new do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :awaiting_review
     end         
    state :awaiting_reviewed do
      event :accept, :transitions_to => :accepted
      event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
    end
    state :accepted
    state :rejected
  end
end
```

I couldn't make it work properly.

Here is my create in the controller that gets triggered when I submit.

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
     @event.user_id = current_user.id
  if signed_in?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save   #well! It seems I couldn't save it! 
      #debugger
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
end
   else 
       redirect_to signin_path
       flash[:notice] = 'Please signin first'
   end
  end
```

It throws and error

```
"ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in EventsController#create"

can't write unknown attribute `workflow_state'
```

Is it the problem with model name? Unfortunately my model itself is 'Event'. Workflow uses event internally too. Was that a problem?

Will edit the post if you need more information.

Comment: do you have any column named 'worflow_state' in your events table?

Comment: no! They didn't mention anything about adding a column in the gem :(

Comment: In rails console, I tried this:
a = Event.find(1)
a.current_state.events
=> {:submit=>#<Workflow::Event:0xbbb52ac8 @name=:submit, @transitions_to=:awaiting_review, @meta={}, @action=nil>}
irb(main):021:0>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have not read the [README](https://github.com/geekq/workflow) completely. You need to add the columns manually by yourself to your events table.

> **Integration with ActiveRecord**
>
> Workflow library can handle the state persistence fully automatically. You only need to define a string field on the table called **workflow_state** and include the workflow mixin in your model class as usual:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Workflow
  workflow do
    # list states and transitions here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add a column '**workflow_state**' to your schema of Event using migration. '**workflow_state**'is default column on which workflow gem works.

---

or you can define your custom column to save the states and define that in model. 
 For example: '**status**' is your custom column then code will be

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Workflow
  workflow_column :status

  # rest of code......
  .....................
end
```

source: https://github.com/geekq/workflow#custom-workflow-database-column